# teradata assistant returned <Error> for simple select query

Tags: sql, teradata

I run a simple query in our company's teradata sql assistant and it returned a records with mostly "".

It's a very simple select query, like `select top 100 * from tablename`.

I used a different computer to run the same query and got valid results.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you getting blank spaces "" or errors ? Also are they different environments like prod or development where you are getting valid results in one environment and blanks in other.

Comment: Check the .NET or ODBC driver connection options to be sure you are using a Unicode (UTF8 or UTF16) session character set.